# Code tag in Chatter

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

While posting an update to Chatter, is there a way to put some part in code tag? Like here at Stack Exchange we can put text in code tag. Is there a way to do it in Chatter like this `Sample Text` ?

Comment: Kindly share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Well, I tried, using ` around the text. Also used actual <code> tag. Both did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a way to post [code snippets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_admin_code_snippets.htm&type=0) in Chatter using the Lightning Experience. You can't write inline code blocks `like this`, but you can make code blocks appear as preformatted paragraphs with some syntax highlighting.

It's also possible to post code snippets using the [Chatter REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_post_feed_element_code_snippet.htm) and methods in the [ConnectApi Apex namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_richtext_code_snippet.htm).